# Getting Connection refused error while using cassandra-stress on cassandra 2.1 Package installation

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to populate some data using cassandra stress tool on a 3 node cluster. I tried to run the casssandra stress multiple times but I got below error. can someone suggest me what is wrong.

```
enter code here`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:     org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at   org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.StressSettings.getRawThriftClient(StressSettings.java:144)
at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.StressSettings.getRawThriftClient(StressSettings.java:110)
at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.SettingsSchema.createKeySpacesThrift(SettingsSchema.java:111)
at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.SettingsSchema.createKeySpaces(SettingsSchema.java:59)
at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.StressSettings.maybeCreateKeyspaces(StressSettings.java:205)
at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction.run(StressAction.java:55)
at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Stress.main(Stress.java:109)
```

Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TFramedTransportFactory.openTransport(TFramedTransportFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.StressSettings.getRawThriftClient(StressSettings.java:124)
    ... 6 more

Comment: We need some details to give you an answer. The command for instance ?

Comment: Hi Sam, any command, like cassandra-stress write n=1000000 is not working there.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. To solve it, I added one more argument "-node "

So my cassandra-stress command became as follows:

```
cassandra-stress write n=50000 -rate threads=40 -node d0.cass.org
```

Where d0.cass.org is the hostname of one of the nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Hi Mohammed, I had the same issue as in the question, your answer worked for me. Thank you so much.

Any guess to resolve this "Failed to connect over JMX; not collecting these stats" issue